# Magento: get country name in a specified language

Tags: magento

I use this code to get the country name,

```
Mage::getModel('directory/country')->loadByCode('DE')->getName();
```

in this sample I get "Germany". How can I get the translation of the country name to show for example "Deutschland" for the german language ?

Note: I don't use the code in a frontendend Module (it must be independant from the Frontend language of the customer).

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course Magento translation engine can be used in your external script:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/translate')->init('de_DE', true);
$country_name = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->loadByCode('DE')->getName();
echo Mage::helper('core')->__($country_name);
```

Or you can use `Zend_Locale` class ar an alternative:

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale('de_DE');
$countries = $locale->getTranslationList('Territory', $locale->getLanguage(), 2);
echo $countries['DE'];
```